# Error: Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\Psr7\uri_for() in Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I am using drupal 8 and creating a custom module while calling a GET request API i am facing below mentioned error.

```
      $client = \Drupal::httpClient();
      $query_str = UrlHelper::buildQuery($query);
      $request = $client->get($url);
      try {
        $response = json_decode($request->getBody(), true);
      }
      catch (RequestException $e) {
        watchdog_exception('settings', $e);
      }
```

`PHP message: Error: Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\Psr7\uri_for()`

**PHP 7.1**
  **Drupal 8**

Comment: So, what is the question? What you did already?